# Indexing on one column slows down query, but indexing on two speeds it up

Tags: sql-server, query-performance

For the following query

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Orders
WHERE status = 'F' AND priority = 'HIGH';
```

When I add an index on the column **status**, the query runtime becomes more than double than if run it without any indexing at all. On the other hand if I put an index on both status and priority like this

```
CREATE INDEX order_status_priority ON order(status, priority);
```

then the runtime becomes around 1/3 of the original runtime without any indexing. Can someone help me understand why this happens? Thanks in advance!

Comment: We could make an educated guess as to what probably is going on but you should provide the execution plans for all three cases so we don't have to guess

Comment: @GerardH.Pille and OP, while likely the high level reasoning that indexing on both columns is faster is because that index would be considered covering since it structures the data on both fields which your query filters on. But the **details** on exactly why the three scenarios are performing differently would be apparent via the execution plans, which explain the *thought process* behind how the data was located and returned for your query. OP, please add the actual execution plans, which you can upload on [Paste The Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan) for a detailed answer.

Comment: What version of SQL-Server?

Comment: What is the result of `select count(1), count(distinct status), count(CASE when status =  'F' then 1 end) from orders`?

Comment: What happens when you run the query a second time, when you have added an index to the `status` column? Does it take the same amount of time? What do the execution plans look like? Copy the execution plan to https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan and post the link in your question. Do this for each query. Then we can tell you what exactly is going on.

Answer (score 3):

It’s unlikely to be any more complex than the following:

1. **No index**: the full table must be read to get your result.
2. **Index on just `status`**: SQL Server uses this index to read all the rows one by one that meet the `status` filter. This can take a long time if there’s a lot of rows that match this filter compared to the overall size of the table. It will not be reading these rows as fast as they would be read using a scan which will read them pages at a time, the index will mean that SQL Server will read the page that a row is on for each row it wants to read - this could mean the same page is read several times.
3. **Index on both columns**: only the index needs to be searched, a chunk of the index will be read (just the bits that match your filters). No need to access the rest of the row as you don’t need any other data other than what’s in the index.

Chances are the optimizer believed that your `status` filter was better than it really was so was excited to use an index on it.

Comment: This was the answer I was too lazy to type. And someone gave a downvote too ashamed to give comment? Up, I say.

Comment: Agreed. A good answer. The only thing I'd add is, look at all three execution plans to validate that this is true.